# How to Debugger in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I added new extension in VSCode. I've added syntax and snippets. It's time for debugging. I searched a lot and couldn't get exactly what I wanted. I want to debug without using tasks.json.

My json files:

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "request": "attach",
            "windows": {
                "preLaunchTask": "windows"
            },
            "linux": {
                "preLaunchTask": "linux"
            },
            "osx": {
                "preLaunchTask": "osx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "windows",
        "command": "echo",
        "args": ["hello windows"],
        "type": "shell"
    },
    {
        "label": "linux",
        "command": "echo",
        "args": ["hello linux"],
        "type": "shell"
    },
    {
        "label": "osx",
        "command": "echo",
        "args": ["hello macOS"],
        "type": "shell"
    }
]
}
```

*Thanks for all your answers.*

Comment: have you looked at the debug doc pages of VSC, and there are specific pages for a lot of languages

Comment: Yes, I looked at the debugging doc.  I have downloaded and reviewed many debugging projects.  But I couldn't understand how they did it.

Comment: do want to add debugging support for your new language or do you want to debug your program

Comment: I already have the debug program.  All I want to do is click the debug and run button on the left while in the project file and be able to see the output in the command prompt.  Example command: exdebug.exe file.ex

Comment: debugging is done with launch configurations, you tell which language you use, create one for your language

Comment: I'm already trying to create for my own language.

Comment: then write a debug adapter for your debugger and specify the schema of the  launch configuration.